# Cross-referencing page range of the whole section with one label

Tags: cross-referencing

How could I create link using `cleveref` package on the section page range?  Now I use the next code

```
\section{Referenced}
  \label{sec:ref-start}
  ...
  \label{sec:ref-end}
```

and then use reference to page range

```
\cpagerefrange{sec:ref-start}{sec:ref-end}
```

How could I write something like

```
\refsectionpagerange{sec:ref-start}
```

with auto-determing of the end of the section?  Does this good practice in LaTeX?

This question [Reference to page-range -> can I avoid using 2 labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/reference-to-page-range-can-i-avoid-using-2-labels) marks the piece of text with two labels, but I want to use one command to mark the section automatically.

Comment: If you have a consistent way of `\label`ling your sections, then it would be possible to automate the end-of-section `\label`. Do you have a consistent way of writing such a `\label`? In your code snippet, you use `sec:X-start` and `sec:X-end` for some section you want to internally call `X`. Would you always use this style? Are you open to alternatives?

Comment: I use the mentioned format in the whole document. I could change it, if necessarily.

Comment: So you already have a start and end label set for each section using the mentioned format?

Comment: Yes, now I have this already, but I want to learn a way to marking the whole section with one command.

Comment: LaTeX's sectioning commands -- `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, etc -- insert elaborate markers on the pages they occur. However, LaTeX doesn't collect information about the range of pages that "belong" to the respective sectioning command. The sectioning commands aren't defined as LaTeX environments, i.e., there is no "`section`" environment and no associated `\begin{section}` and `\end{section}` instructions. Thus, short of some major hacking of all sectioning-related commands I can't picture how your stated objective could be achieved using LaTeX. (ConTeXt may be a different matter.)

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `zref` (although not particularly needed, but it is a very  convenient and powerful package), using one label per entity, i.e. `section` etc.

The `\RegisterPostLabelHook` macro from `xassoccnt` package adds 'another' labeling command that is executed after `\label`, here it is `zlabel`. A disadvantage of this approach is that any `\label` call generates two label entries in the `.aux` file instead of only one. If this is not wanted, rename all `\label` occurences into `\zlabel` and comment out `\RegisterPostLabelHook`.

The label information is evaluated in `\refsectionpageref` and displayed accordingly.

The macro checks also whether both labels appear on the same page, but it does not eject any warning whether the label is defined or the label pointing to the later entity is used as first argument, nor does it check whether the labels used are tied to `section` counters here, so mixing of labels belonging to different counters is possible, unfortunately.

The starred version of `\refsectionpageref` suppresses hyperlinks if this feature is preferred.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[user,hyperref,counter]{zref}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\hyperlink}[2]{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extractsectionlabel}{sm}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#2}{}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \zref@extract{#2}{page}%
    }{%
      \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#2}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#2}{page}}%
    }%
  }%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\refsectionpagerange}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{\zref@extract{#2}{page}}{\zref@extract{#3}{page}}%
    \extractsectionlabel*{#2}%
    \else
    \extractsectionlabel*{#2} -- \extractsectionlabel*{#3}%
    \fi
  }{%
    \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{\zref@extract{#2}{page}}{\zref@extract{#3}{page}}%
    \extractsectionlabel{#2}%
    \else
    \extractsectionlabel{#2} -- \extractsectionlabel{#3}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\RegisterPostLabelHook{\zlabel}

\begin{document}

See \refsectionpagerange{foo}{fooend}

\section{Foo} \label{foo}


\section{Foobar} \label{foobar}


\blindtext[10]
\clearpage

\section{Fooend} \label{fooend}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]